# Create Database or table etc at runtime when using LINQ or Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

we know that when we use ado.net then we can create database or table at run time programatically like

```
 String str;
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection ("Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");

str = "CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase ON PRIMARY " +
    "(NAME = MyDatabase_Data, " +
    "FILENAME = 'C:\\MyDatabaseData.mdf', " +
    "SIZE = 2MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
    "LOG ON (NAME = MyDatabase_Log, " +
    "FILENAME = 'C:\\MyDatabaseLog.ldf', " +
    "SIZE = 1MB, " +
    "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
    "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
try 
{
    myConn.Open();
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
finally
{
if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    myConn.Close();
}
}
```

so i am learning LINQ and EF. so i am interested to know that can i create table or database at runtime with the help of LINQ or EF. please let me know and if possible then please give me some link of good article with similar subject.

thanks
Tridip

Comment: do you know how to open a connection and execute commands using EF? If so, try to execute a CREATE TABLE command. If does not work show your code and ask help based on the actual code you are trying to use.